# TFS build renaming the cspkg file

Tags: tfs

I currently use TFS build for my Azure cloud service project. 
as a output of that .cspkg and .cscfg file is created after the successful build.
is there any way to add the $(Build.BuildNumber) to my .cspkg file
say for eg: currently my output file looks like
SchoolWebPortalAzure.cspkg 
is it possible to rename like SchoolWebPortal_1.0.0.1.cspkg in the tfs build definition.

thanks,

kind regards,
Snegha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Run Command Line task or do it in a PowerShell script in build.

1). Add the [Inline Powershell](https://pgroene.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/using-the-inline-powershell-vsts-task/) task from the marketplace before the copy task in build definition.

2).Enter the following Powershell in the text area

```
 Param (
[string]$pathToFileToRename
)

Rename-Item $pathToFileToRename  Helloworld_$(Build.BuildNumber).exe
```

3). Enter any required arguments in the arguments text box (you could
    use environment variables) e.g. `-pathToFileToRename $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\somepath\CurrentName.exe`

Then you will get the renamed file in the drop folder.
[image]